# D3.js SVG not clickable inside angular-ui tabs

Tags: angularjs, svg, d3.js, angular-ui

I'm trying to use D3 inside of an angular-ui tab. Specifically, a clickable canvas where I can add and drag little black circles. If I put the svg element inside the tab, no clicks get registered. If I put the svg element outside of the tabset, the clicks seem to take and my callbacks executed. Is there something I'm forgetting to do on the angular-ui side of things?